# dbus not working with python3 on a virtual environment?

Tags: python, opencv, virtualenv, dbus, virtualenvwrapper

I set up a virtual environment named "ComputerVision" with virtualwrapper, virtualen and pthon3.

Everything works fine except of importing dbus in my python script.
I want to use python3 but as you can see:
-dbus can be importet with python2 not python3
-cv2 can be importet with python3 not python 2

```
(ComputerVision) pi@raspberrypi:/ $ python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dbus
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'dbus'
>>> import cv2
>>> exit()
(ComputerVision) pi@raspberrypi:/ $ python2
Python 2.7.13 (default, Sep 26 2018, 18:42:22) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dbus
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv2
>>> exit()
(ComputerVision) pi@raspberrypi:/ $ pip install dbus-python3
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting dbus-python3
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dbus-python3 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for dbus-python3
(ComputerVision) pi@raspberrypi:/ $ pip install python3-dbus
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting python3-dbus
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python3-dbus (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for python3-dbus
(ComputerVision) pi@raspberrypi:/ $ pip install python-dbus
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting python-dbus
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-dbus (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for python-dbus
(ComputerVision) pi@raspberrypi:/ $
```

How can I fix it, to be able to import dbus to my python3 script??

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install dbus-python library for Python3:

```
pip3 install dbus-python
```

Comment: Still not wirking: ```(ComputerVision) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pip3 install dbus-python
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: dbus-python in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (1.2.8)
(ComputerVision) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dbus
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'dbus'
```

Comment: I can only suggest starting over on fresh virtual environment. I have just successfully installed dbus-python on Python 3 venv and it does load without error.

Comment: what have you done or how did you do that? its not working for me...? so 
```python3```
and then import dbus
import cv2
is working for you??